# Jquery .load not working with PHP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I am currently working on a chat system experiment, and have run into an issue.

**This is my code:**

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   function getUpdates() {
      $('#updates').load('chatlister.php', function() {window.alert('Load was performed.');});
   }
   setTimeout(getUpdates(), 1000);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>The updates are:</p>
   <div id="updates"></div>
</body>
```

For some reason, the jQuery `.load()` function is not loading anything into the "updates" `<div>` section of the page. I checked `chatlister.php` and made sure that it had output, and I also made sure that the two files are in the same directory. I am very new to jQuery, so please bear with me. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to be created so run only after the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#updates').load('chatlister.php', function() {window.alert('Load was performed.');});
});
```

If you want to run it every seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var getUpdates = function() {
      $('#updates').load('chatlister.php', function() {window.alert('Load was performed.');});
   }
   setInterval(getUpdates, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked (with a bit of tweaking). When i put the call to `getUpdates()` inside of the `document.ready` code, it worked. Maybe add that to your answer. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: One more thing, if you dont mind. How do I make the `.load` script repeat every second? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Edited for you. Please accept if it solved your problem.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Just make sure to change it from `Timeout` to `Interval`. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your code in this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// Code here
});
```

Because the code is never being executed, either that, or your php is wrong.

You should have a look at [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)